# How to check DOMElement setIdAttribute() is set?

Tags: php, dom

Assuming I have following code.

```
$newdom = new DOMDocument();
$elem = new DOMElement('div');
$text = new DOMText('testing');

$elem = $newdom->importNode($elem,true);
$newdom->appendChild($elem);
$text = $newdom->importNode($text,true);
$elem->appendChild($text);
$elem->setAttribute('id','foo');
$elem->setIdAttribute('id',true);
$elem->setIdAttribute('id',true); //set twice will cause C14N() fail
echo $newdom->getElementById('foo')->C14N();
```

If the setIdAttribute() is called twice, then C14N() will not work. Now, my problem is, if I have a DOMElement as an input to a function, in order to make the DOMElement can be getElementById(), I need to setIdAttribute(). But since it cannot be set twice, how do I check whether it is set or not?

Answer (score 0):

After hours of trying, just after this post, I just found the solution. There is isId() from DOMAttr which allows to check the attribute.