# PHP standard DOMElement::setIdAttribute bug

Tags: php, xml

I managed to reproduce a bug, which seems to be in native PHP library, that manipulates XML. The catch is, when DOMElement::setIdAttribute is called twice on an element, the result that you get is not what you expect. Here it is:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');

$element = $dom->createElement('test', 'root');

$dom->appendChild($element);

$element->setAttribute("id", 123);
$element->setIdAttribute("id", true);

$node = $element->getAttributeNode("id");
echo $node->isId(), "\n";

$element->setIdAttribute("id", true);
echo $node->isId(), "\n";
```

And in console we see just

```
1
```

So, the second call to `$node->isId()` returns false. My question is whether it is a real bug or a feature? I tested similar methods in Java and it works just as expected - not like in PHP.

EDIT

I investigated the source code of PHP and it seems, like the buggy behaviour is in [these](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/dom/element.c#L1027-L1032) lines:

```
static void php_set_attribute_id(xmlAttrPtr attrp, bool is_id) /* {{{ */
{
 if (is_id == 1 && attrp->atype != XML_ATTRIBUTE_ID) {
    xmlChar *id_val;

    id_val = xmlNodeListGetString(attrp->doc, attrp->children, 1);
    if (id_val != NULL) {
        xmlAddID(NULL, attrp->doc, id_val, attrp);
        xmlFree(id_val);
    }
} else {
    if (attrp->atype == XML_ATTRIBUTE_ID) {
        xmlRemoveID(attrp->doc, attrp);
        attrp->atype = 0;
    }
}
}
```

As you can see, if `is_id == 1` and `attrp->atype == XML_ATTRIBUTE_ID`, the ID is still removed from the attributes, which looks like nonsense.

Comment: Boolean `true` converts to `1` and  `false` to `0`. So if you set it to `true`, it is probably converted to `1`, hence the result. Try setting it to `false` and see if it returns `0`.

Comment: @Michel. There is nothing wrong with 1 and 0 being printed. The wrong thing is that 1 is not printed the second time

Comment: Sorry, read it wrong. Maybe [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16099343/1685196) gives an answer.

Comment: @Michel. Obviously, not. That question is about - how to check if attribute is ID. My question, is why when we call setIdAttribute twice, the ID is removed from the attribute

Comment: @Michel. Probably, you have not noticed, that I called `setIdAttribute("id", true)` twice. And second call must not revoke identity from the attribute.

Comment: I think, I will make a pull request to PHP source code now.